# Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 "Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal"

Tags: upgrade

I am not able to upgrade to the latest version 13.04. The error is:

```
Failed to download repository information
Check your Internet connection.
Details
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs,
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-i386/Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs,
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment the cdrom entry out in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, it's likely one of the first lines in the file. Another way to do it is the `Software sources` graphical tool.

Comment: The update now installs correctly and reports there are no updates to install, so I'm up to date... THANK YOU both so much.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command...

`sudo software-properties-gtk`

In the window which opens up,

Deselect the CD-ROM entry, in the `Installable from CD-ROM/DVD`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I only got part way. When I try to save the file /etc/apt/sources.list logged in as superuser I get the error: "You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again."

Comment: SOLVED part of this and grimpitch solved the other part! The update now installs correctly and reports there are no updates to install, so I'm up to date... THANK YOU both so much.